# AWK How to take value from header and print it in columns?

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns, duplicate

I have to get some values from header in txt files and duplicate them as column the number of rows change from file to file , here is an example.

Input file:

```
PROJECT : PRK33
X_COR : 258524
Y_COR : 225898
DATUM : 874

DEPTH   TIME

0        0
1        7
2        16
3        20
```

Output file:

```
0        0    258524 225898 874
1        7    258524 225898 874
2        16   258524 225898 874
3        20   258524 225898 874
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible straightforward way, based on the assumption that the headers are exactly as you provided and the data starts from line 8

1. Match header lines of interest, keeping their values
2. Starting from first data line, append values to the output with some nice fomatting

   awk -F":" '/^X_COR/ { x=$2 } ; /^Y_COR/ { y=$2 } ; /^DATUM/ { d=$2 } ;NR>7 { print sprintf("%-20s %-10d %-10d %-10d",$0,x,y,d) }' YourInputFile

You may want to adjust line number and formatting if those differs from your example

Answer (score 0):

Using a straight copy paste of OP post and assuming only one header set per file

```
awk -F":" '$2+0{a=a"\t"$2}$1~/[^0-9. ]+$/{print $0a}' file1

0        0       258524  225898  874
1        7       258524  225898  874
2        16      258524  225898  874
3        20      258524  225898  874
```

Break on `:`

if `$2` is numeric, `$2+0`is true, then it is x, y or z so compose it into a string as you go

Otherwise if `$1` contains numerics `$1~/^[0-9. ]+$/` it is data so print it plus the composed string

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && NR<5{h=h OFS $NF} NR>7{print $0 h}' file
0        0 258524 225898 874
1        7 258524 225898 874
2        16 258524 225898 874
3        20 258524 225898 874
```

or maybe this is more like what you want to do, e.g. if the headers can be in varying input order but you want to enforce a specific output order:

```
$ awk '/:/{f[$1]=$NF} NR>7{print $0, f["X_COR"], f["Y_COR"], f["DATUM"]}' file
0        0 258524 225898 874
1        7 258524 225898 874
2        16 258524 225898 874
3        20 258524 225898 874
```